# How can Quasar Dialog be mounted under root or parent component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

The dynamically created Dialog is mounted under the `<body>` tag by default, so that the global Provide and Inject cannot be used. How can Dialog be mounted under `div#app` or mounted under parent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always mounted either under `<body>` (non-SSR) or nowhere (SSR mode) - not just "by default". Just look at the sources - https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/blob/dev/ui/src/utils/private/global-nodes.js#L6

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the provide on the Vue `app`, using [`app.provide()`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-provide) instead of an `<App/>` component. For example, in the entry script

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { Quasar, Dialog } from 'quasar'
import App from './App.vue'
createApp(App)
    .provide('name', value)
    .use(Quasar, {
        plugins: {
            Dialog,
        }
    })
    .mount('#app')
```

Then you will be able to use `inject()` the same item in Quasar dialog children, even though the dialog is mounted under `<body>`.